# Typescript optional type inferring

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Not sure if question is right, but I want it to infer the result type but actually have no clue how to do it.

Here how i did it now:

```js
type StateSetter<S> = (prevState: S) => S;
type ResolvableHookState<S> = S | StateSetter<S>;

export function resolveHookState<S>(state: S): S;
export function resolveHookState<S>(state: StateSetter<S>, currentState?: S): S;
export function resolveHookState<S>(state: ResolvableHookState<S>, currentState?: S): S {
  if (typeof state === 'function') {
    return (state as StateSetter<S>)(currentState as S);
  }

  return state;
}
```

Here is how i want to use it:

```js
function someFunction(initialState: ResolvableHookState<number> = 0){
  const resolvedState = resolveHookState(initialState);
}
```

Idea is to make `resolveHookState(initialState)` return the number type, but for obvious reasons it returns `ResolvableHookState<number>`

I've tried to make it via infering but it seems not to work as i expect.

```js
type ResolvableHookStateType<S extends ResolvableHookState<any>> = S extends StateSetter<infer T> ? T : S;
```

**[UPD 1]**
After some tinkering ended up with this:

```js
export type StateSetter<S> = (prevState?: S) => S;

export type ResolvableHookState<S> = S | StateSetter<S>;

type ResolvableHookStateType<S> = S extends ResolvableHookState<infer T> ? T : never;

export function resolveHookState<S>(state: S): ResolvableHookStateType<S>;
export function resolveHookState<S>(state: StateSetter<S>, currentState?: S): ResolvableHookStateType<S>;
export function resolveHookState<S>(state: ResolvableHookState<S>, currentState?: S): ResolvableHookStateType<S> {
  if (typeof state === 'function') {
    return (state as StateSetter<S>)(currentState) as ResolvableHookStateType<S>;
  }

  return state as ResolvableHookStateType<S>;
```

But i'm not sure it is the most elegant way to solve the problem.

Comment: Be careful with the usage of `as` keyword, it just tells TypeScript to shut up.. :) What happens if I want to store functions in my state (this is what you ignore with the first `as`)? What if I call `resolveHookState` with a stateSetter and no current state (second `as`)?

Comment: @Grabofus i'm making custorm React hook that should be used as it's native `useState`, it's arguments can be a value or function that returns a value, if it is a function it is invoked with no arguments and it's result used as state.
In this part it will act exactly as react (and if you want to store a function you have to wrap it with another function).

Comment: @Grabofus Furthermore, react's `useState` hook returns a function that can set new state. It can be a value or function too, but this time function will receive 1 argument - current state value.
So if i am right (i hope i am %)) i made a function that covers both usecases.

This function will not be exposed to users, so ivalid use-cases would be caught by tests

Comment: The only problem is, if `<S>` is of type function (but not a StateSetter), you'll invoke it, instead of saving it as state. Please have a look at my answer below to see if it fits your scenario. :)

Comment: Edit: Removed the answer, seem to have some issues.. I'll revisit it and update it soon if you don't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Callable<ReturnType> {
  (...args: any[]): ReturnType;
}

type GenericReturnType<ReturnType, F> = F extends Callable<ReturnType>
  ? ReturnType
  : never;

function someFunction(initialState: ResolvableHookState<number> = 0){
  const resolvedState = GenericReturnType<number, typeof initialState>;
}
```

[This](https://dev.to/busypeoples/notes-on-typescript-returntype-3m5a) article might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with keeping `as` around, this works

```
export type StateSetter<S> = (prevState?: S) => S

export type ResolvableHookState<S> = S | StateSetter<S>

export function resolveHookState<S>(
  state: ResolvableHookState<S>,
  currentState?: S
): S {
  if (typeof state === 'function') {
    return (state as StateSetter<S>)(currentState)
  } else {
    return state as S
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get. One thing to keep in mind is your state cannot be of type `Function` otherwise you wouldn't be able to tell which overload you're trying to handle.

```
type State<S> = Exclude<S, Function>;
type StateSetter<S> = (prevState: S) => S;
type ResolvableHookState<S> = State<S> | StateSetter<S>;

function resolveHookState<S>(state: State<S>): S;
function resolveHookState<S>(stateSetter: StateSetter<State<S>>, currentState: State<S>): S;
function resolveHookState<S>(stateOrStateSetter: ResolvableHookState<S>, currentState?: State<S>): S {
  if (typeof stateOrStateSetter === 'function') {
    if (currentState !== undefined) {
      // From: StateSetter<S> | (Exclude<S, Function> & Function)
      // Not sure why (Exclude<S, Function> & Function) doesn't resolve to never
      const stateSetter = stateOrStateSetter as StateSetter<S>; 
      return stateSetter(currentState);
    } else {
      // If you call resolveHookState with a stateSetter and no currentState
      // This should not be possible based on the method signatures.
      throw new Error('Oops?'); 
    }
  } else {
    const state = stateOrStateSetter;
    return state;
  }
}

// Call with state
resolveHookState(0);

// Or with setter
const stateSetter = (prevState: number) => prevState + 1;
resolveHookState(stateSetter, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you alot!
Basing on your solution i've made one that fully fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on @Grabofus solution made my own:

```js
export type StateSetter<S> = (prevState: S) => S;
export type InitialStateSetter<S> = () => S;

export type InitialHookState<S> = S | InitialStateSetter<S>;
export type HookState<S> = S | StateSetter<S>;
export type ResolvableHookState<S> = S | StateSetter<S> | InitialStateSetter<S>;

export function resolveHookState<S>(newState: S | InitialStateSetter<S>): S;
export function resolveHookState<S>(newState: Exclude<HookState<any>, StateSetter<any>>, currentState: S): S;
export function resolveHookState<S>(newState: StateSetter<S>, currentState: S): S;
export function resolveHookState<S>(newState: ResolvableHookState<S>, currentState?: S): S {
  if (typeof newState === 'function') {
    return (newState as Function)(currentState);
  }

  return newState as S;
}
```